# Why doesn't the following program work?

Tags: java

I can't figure out why the following program doesn't work. Please help me where did I make a mistake. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[100];
        int largestNumber = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter numbers. When you want to finish, type 'finish'.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
                    numbers[counter] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            if (!sc.hasNextInt() && !sc.hasNext("finish")) {
                System.out.println("It's neither number nor 'finish'.");
            }
        }

        while (!sc.hasNext("finish"));

        for (int x : numbers) {
            if (x > largestNumber) {
                largestNumber = x;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + largestNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Compile error?  Runtime error?  Unexpected result?  Please explain.

Comment: I get InputMismatchException.

Comment: and your re typing...?

Comment: A) Try posting the full exception and stacktrace so we can narrow it down and B) How are we supposed to know what input you're giving?

Comment: I'm typing either numbers or strings.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at LargestNumber.main(LargestNumber.java:17)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the doc:

Throws:
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, **or is out of range**

So i thing you could do this instead:

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < numbers.length) {
  if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    numbers[counter++] = sc.nextInt();
  } else {
    if (sc.hasNext("finish")) {
      sc.close();
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("It's neither number nor 'finish'.");
      sc.next();
    }
  }
}

for (int x : numbers) {
  if (x > largestNumber) {
largestNumber = x;
  }
}

System.out.println("The largest number is: " + largestNumber);
```

hope that helps

Comment: It's not me who downvoted, but changing if to while doesn't work here.

Comment: I downvoted becaue I really didn't think this would work, and then the OP verified.

Comment: @user2637870 test it again and tell me if is it what you want

Comment: It never tests for "finish". It can't be right.

Comment: I think that the check hasNextInt has to be done inside the for

Comment: Unfortunately when i enter any string (even "finish") it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: i forgot to 'avance' the scanner in the cases of not number. It should work for you now

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Scanner` is unnessecarily complicated and doesn't work to much of the time. Here's how to do it the old fashioned way:

```
public class LargestNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int largestNumber=0;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers. When you want to finish, type 'finish'.");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while (!(line = r.readLine()).equals("finish")) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (val > largestNumber)
                largestNumber = val;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + largestNumber);
    }
}
```

For this, enter each number on a new line. I used a shorter algorithm here, which is to read one number, and if it is bigger than the maximum so far, the new number is the maximum so far

Comment: I think it's the way OP is *using* Scanner is overly complicated. He made a mess out of a simple requirement.

Comment: I think your code need a closed curly brace more...

Comment: @AndreaParodi you are right

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
    do {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
                numbers[counter] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        if (!sc.hasNextInt() && !sc.hasNext("finish")) {
            System.out.println("It's neither number nor 'finish'.");
        }
    }

    while (!sc.hasNext("finish"));
```

makes no sense. You:

1. test if the next thing in the input is an integer;
2. attempt to parse **ten next tokens**, assuming that they are all integers;
3. at the eleventh token you check whether it's another integer or "finish";
4. throw an exception if it's neither;
5. repeat everything if it's not "finish".

What you should actually do is something much, much simpler:

1. check next token:

   - if it's "finish", you're done;
   - if it's an integer, parse it;
   - otherwise throw error;
2. repeat this for up to 100 times;
3. you are done accepting input. Proceed to processing it.